# How can I change default settings in Eclipse for CSS and HTML

Tags: html, eclipse, css

I use my Eclipse Juno version to create HTML and CSS files. When I create a new HTML and CSS file, it is created as *HTML 4.01 Transitional* in case of HTML and CSS normal, not as CSS3.

I tried to change the settings from Project Properties-Web Content Settings-Document type-HTML5 and CSS Profile-CSS3 Cascading Style Sheet Level 3 and then Apply and Ok.

However, when I return to the main workspace the settings automatically change and return to default, HTML 4.01 Transitional, and Normal CSS. So I think that changing the default settings another way can help me. Also, if there is any plugin for solving this problem in Eclipse please let me know.

N.B. I don't know what is the default CSS version is, so I am using *Normal CSS*. Hope it won't be problem to understand.

Comment: Highlighting every other word as code is incorrect and makes your question absolutely hideous to read.

Comment: @BradMace edited the question. Check it.

Comment: @Bart I would like to know when to use _italics_ and when **bold**?

Comment: @Mistu4u Hi. I know it was a long time ago but... have you ever checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Create your HTML files using File > New > Other... then Web > HTML file. Follow the wizard until third step where you can select the HTML template to use.